# How to install Waterfox browser on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: software-installation, firefox, 64-bit, alternative

I want to install the 64 bits version of Firefox - [Waterfox](http://www.waterfoxproject.org/download.php) on Ubuntu 12.04 system. Since the browser is not available in the software center and I was not able to find any examples of installing it I want to know has anyone do this?

Please,provide more installation details since I am Linux user for few weeks only.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do this? Does the amd64 [Firefox package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/firefox) not provide a 64-bit build of Firefox?

Comment: Hmmm... As far as I can see waterfox is just 64bit version of Firefox *for Windows* as a stable version of 64bit Firefox is not available for Windows, though it is available for Linux and OS X. Windows can have 64bit versions of the alpha and nightly version of Firefox. However I think 64bit firefox will soon become offical, so Waterfox may become pointless - e.g. http://www.techradar.com/news/software/applications/mozilla-s-64-bit-firefox-browser-will-touch-down-in-spring-2015-1267857 , though I think I found a official source a while ago looking at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis

Comment: BTW if you are using 64bit linxu you should get 64bit firefox etc - you may be able to check by looking at `about:buildconfig`,`about:support` and looking for `x86_64`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waterfox is not available for Ubuntu(Linux). To install Waterfox on Ubuntu machine you need Wine package installed.

**Wine**

> Wine is a compatibility layer which allows Windows applications to run
>   on Linux by translating Windows system calls into native Linux calls.

Download the Waterfox installer from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/waterfoxproj/files/latest/download) and install it using Wine.

or the alternate way is to install Firefox 64 bit. http://www.firefox64bit.com

[Download link](http://www.firefox64bit.com/firefox.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2)  for Firefox 64bit OS

Installation steps:

```
cd /tmp
wget 'http://www.firefox64bit.com/firefox.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2'
```

Extract the file to /opt or ~/firefox directory

```
sudo tar -jxvf firefox.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 -C /opt
```

or

```
tar -jxvf firefox.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 -C ~/firefox
```

Answer (score 3):

Waterfox 32 & 64 IS now available for Linux/Ubuntu at https://www.waterfoxproject.org/downloads .

It is available as a compressed archive. I installed it in Linux Mint 18.1 like this:

I d/l'd it to my home, then I right clicked on it and selected "extract here". After which, I opened a console and typed in "sudo tar -jxvf waterfox-50.1.0.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 waterfox/" (without the parentheses) .

I then went to my "run an application" launcher and typed in waterfox. Joi`la, she worky. Then I created a desktop launcher for it and moved it to a panel.

Hopes this help ya'.

I had a file simply named "waterfox".